# widescreen test on normal screen locally

Tags: css

Our layout has fallen fowl of widescreen because I didn't have a widescreen. Also nvr thought to test it on a widescreen DOH!

I have found tools that allow me to do what I want BUT are there ones that work locally? It's not like I can take down the a live site/expose internal servers just to test it.

Having to upload it everytime as well is PITA especially if you;re not gud at css.

Comment: A simple test is just to zoom your browser out. (`Ctrl`+`-` in most browsers) It's not ideal, but it gives a good way to try out a size "larger" than your screen.

Comment: Can't you just unzoom or modify size of your window (even if it goes out of your screen viewport)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the responsive tool, native in google Chrome.

1. Go on the page you want to test
2. Press f12
3. Press the little screen button on the top left corner

[image: Screen button]

4. Select "responsive" in the menu
5. Insert the width/high you want to test

[image: Select the width/height]